# Changing keyboard language layout in linux mint doesn't work for second time

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I have added a second keyboard language layout (Persian) in ***Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon*** and in the keyboard setting I've set it to use shortcut <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to change the layout.

It works fine when the selected layout is the primary (US English) and the shortcut changes the layout to secondary layout (Persian) but when I want to change from (Persian) to (English) it doesn't work and I have to use mouse and change it from the panel icon.

I've changed the shortcut to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> but the problem still remains.

Comment: That's weird! I have the same problem with Linux Mint 20.2 Mate when I use win + space. But now I added alt + shift and it works fine.

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/1134384/85695

Answer (score 2):

My solution which solved this issue in Linux Mint 20.3:

1. Open **Keyboard Preferences**:

   Linux Mint Menu > Control Center > under category Hardware : keyboard
2. Tab Layouts > **Reset to Defaults**
3. **Add** your Layout :

   - Tab Layouts > Add
   - By Language : Persian
   - Variants : Persian
   - Add
4. Change the shortcut to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> :

   Tab Layouts > Options > Switching to another layout > <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon, I went through this steps and my issue fixed:

1. Open **Keyboard Settings**
2. Choose **Layouts**
3. On right bottom corner, open **Options...**
4. Click on **Switching to another layout**
5. Select `Alt+Ctrl` or `Alt+Shift`  (you can select both)

> Attention always press `Alt` first and press `Ctrl` or `Shift` second

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I found that it could be done with:

<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>

You could check:

> Menu > Keyboard > Layouts > Options

For your custom shortcut. Or `Reset to Defaults` and the above combination should work.